# SVG elliptical arc

Tags: svg

I been struggling for hours to solve this, I'm trying to draw elliptical arc to fill up the spaces circled in red, can I have some sample code for it?

[image: The elliptical arc in grey area]

EDIT:

Since shape is generated using JavaScript, I will add SVG Elements generated from browser:

```
<svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: white; padding: 0px 10px; user-select: none;" id="chart">

    <path d="M 375,300 a 1 1 0 0 0 -300 0" stroke="lightgray" fill="lightgray"></path>

    <path id="__currentVal__" d="M 75,300 l 150,0 l -106.06601717798213,-106.06601717798212 " stroke="skyblue" fill="skyblue"></path>
</svg>
```

The blue shape will be the element with id `__currentVal__`, the elliptical arc command will inserted at end of command `M 75,300 l 150,0 l -106.06601717798213,-106.06601717798212`

The expected output will be like this (edited using MS Paint):
[image: Expected shape output]

Comment: 1: If you have "been struggling for hours to solve this", then you will have code that readers can evaluate, so please post it. 2: Requests for things like tutorials or documentation are defined in the Help Center as being off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: First please try this: `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#ddd"/> 
  <path d="M50,50
           L5,50
           A45,45 0 0 1 27.5,11.028
           L50,50z" fill="skyblue"/>
</svg>`

Comment: Take a look at the d attribute of the path. This is the part drawing the arc: `A45,45 0 0 1 27.5,11.028` where 45 is the radius if the circle and 27.5,11.028 are the x and y coordinates of the point where the arc ends. The arc begins in this case at the last point of the previous line (5,50). In order to be able to help you I would need to know the radius of the arc the starting point and the ending point. **Please edit your question and add those values**

Comment: @underscore_d I only have the code that draws the blue triangle, I had no idea about how to draw a simple elliptical arc, but I would re-edit the question with code, thanks.

Comment: @enxaneta All coordinates are generated randomly using JavaScript, maybe I try edit the question with what it's generated from browser, thanks.

Comment: When you update your question, please also make it clear whether you actually want (a) just the shape circled in red, or (b) the blue shape updated to include the circled area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the d attribute you are using: `d="M 75,300 l 150,0 l -106.06601717798213,-106.06601717798212 "`

`M 75,300` means that you are moving to the point x:75, y:300.

Since you are using lower case commands those are relative commands. For instance `l 150,0` means that you are moving 150 units in x from 75 to 225. The y doesn't change meaning that the y:300. The center of the arc is in this point: x:225,y:300.

This part of the command is also letting me know that the radius of the arc is 150.

Next the path (`l -106.06601717798213,-106.06601717798212`) goes from the previous point x:225 y:300 to the point x:225-106.06601717798213 = 118.93398282201787, y:300-106.06601717798212 = 193.93398282201787

I'm drawing a small circle to visualise this point (x:118.93398282201, y:193.93398282201787 ). The arc will start here. Also I'm drawing another small circle in the point x:75,y:300. The arc will end here. Now I can draw the arc: `M118.93398282201,193.93398282201787 A 150,150 0 0 0 75,300`

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="background-color: white; padding: 0px 10px; user-select: none;" id="chart">

    <path d="M 375,300 a 150 150 0 0 0 -300 0" stroke="lightgray" fill="lightgray"></path>

    <path id="__currentVal__"d="M 75,300 l 150,0 l -106.06601717798213,-106.06601717798212 " stroke="skyblue" fill="none" ></path>
  
  <circle cx="75" cy="300" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="118.93398282201" cy="193.93398282201787" r="5"/>
  
  
 <path d="M118.93398282201,193.93398282201787A150,150 0 0 0 75,300" />
</svg>
```

If you happen to need to draw the arc in the same path as the actual blue triangle you can do this: you start your path with the arc, then you use the d attribute of your path without the first (move to) command. You don't need to move to this point since you are already there (the arc is ending in this point)

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="background-color: white; padding: 0px 10px; user-select: none;" id="chart">

    <path d="M 375,300 a 150 150 0 0 0 -300 0" stroke="lightgray" fill="lightgray"></path>

   
  
  <circle cx="75" cy="300" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="118.93398282201" cy="193.93398282201787" r="5"/>
  
  
 <path d="M118.93398282201,193.93398282201787A150,150 0 0 0 75,300
 l 150,0 l -106.06601717798213,-106.06601717798212 " stroke="skyblue" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

You can remove those 2 small circles I've drawn as helpers to let me visualise the points of your path.

Comment: What a detailed answer! Thanks a lot for your answer to this question!